# How to implement Recursion

Tags: java, class, math, recursion, addition

Hello I am trying to implement recursion in one of my assignments.

These are my classes.

```
public class Bear implements TotemPole {

  int bearCount;
  public Bear(TotemPole rest){}

  public Bear() {
    bearCount = 3;
  }

  public int power() {
    return  + 5;
  }

  public int height(){
    return bearCount + 5;
  }

  public boolean chiefPole(int bearCount){
    if(this.bearCount >= bearCount){
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

// SNAKE CLASS

```
public class Snake implements TotemPole {

  public Snake(TotemPole rest){}
  int bearCount;

  public Snake() {
    bearCount = 0;
  }

  public int power() {
    return + 3;
  }

  public int height(){
    return bearCount + 1;
  }

  public boolean chiefPole(int bearCount){
    if(this.bearCount >= bearCount){
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

// EAGLE CLASS

```
public class Eagle implements TotemPole {

  int bearCount;
  public Eagle(){
    bearCount = 0;
  }

  public int power() {
    return + 2;
  }

  public int height(){
    return  bearCount + 1;
  }

  public boolean chiefPole(int bearCount){
    if(this.bearCount >= bearCount){
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Basically I am trying to figure out how recursion works for the power() method.  The tester is expecting to get a value of 26.  However, my code is not working.  I am new to java so any help is appreciated.

//TESTER

```
p1 = new Bear(
                new Bear(
                   new Snake(
                      new Snake(
                         new Snake(
                            new Bear(
                               new Eagle()))))));
```

Comment: I don't see any recursion

Comment: then can you see why the tester is failing?

Comment: @SailorJerry This question isn't clear. Why and how should power() return 26? You are referring to power() of which class? Do you know what is recursion?

Comment: As my understanding, you would like the method power() is calculated base on the bearCount and the TotemPole. Is that right?!

Comment: In your constructors you never assign `rest` to a field.. That's probably a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on your comments, I think you need to add TotemPole properties for each class. Then in the power() method, just need to calculate it. For example in the class Bear you can add:

```
class Bear implements TotemPole {

      int bearCount;
      TotemPole totem;
      public Bear(TotemPole totem){
          bearCount = 3;
          this.totem = totem;
      }


      public int power() {
          int result = 0;
          if(totem == null) {
              result = 5;
          } else {
             result = totem.power() + 5;
          }
        return result;
      }


      public Bear() {
        bearCount = 3;
      }

      public int height(){
        return bearCount + 5;
      }

      public boolean chiefPole(int bearCount){
        if(this.bearCount >= bearCount){
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
```

Same as with other classes.
Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is nothing different about recursion in Java than recursion in any other language. So if you know recursion, it should be easy to implement in Java.
2. What are you trying to achieve in this code?

   p1 = new Bear(
                   new Bear(
                      new Snake(
                         new Snake(
                            new Snake(
                               new Bear(
                                  new Eagle()))))));

Why are you passing a reference of 1 object as a parameter to a constructor of another class?

Look at this code, for example:

```
new Bear(new Eagle())
```

Does your class Bear have any constructor which takes Eagle object as a parameter?
No.
There is  a gap between what you are doing and what you need done.

Comment: Basically I need the output of tester to equal 26.  This is done by adding all of the power() methods together. So it would be 5 + 5 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 5 + 2.  Im trying to understand how to do this.

Comment: Output is not important. Knowing what made you pass an object of 1 class to a constructor of another class is important so that you can understand the right concepts.